# add new voices to freeTTS other than us voices

Tags: java, voice, freetts, mbrola

I am working on a speech recognition project, therefore I need to have audio files for more than thousands of words. I have done everything correctly in order to use `Mbrola` voices in `FreeTTS` but I can only use `us1,us2,us3`. It doesn't 
recognize any other voices.

When I try to use `mbrola_en1` I get this error:

> Invalid Voice: Mbrola_en1
>       valid voices: alan kevin kevin16 mbrola_us1 mbrola_us2 mbrola_us3

I read all the questions related to this but unfortunately none of them are answered.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The MbrolaVoiceDirectory class is hardcoded for us1, us2, us3. I copied the source code of the file to my own project, pointed the freetts.voices environment variable at it, and gently hacked it to look for the other filenames.